# SSH Error while trying to connect to Google Compute Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openssh, gcloud

I am running below command to connect to google compute instance:

**gcloud compute ssh example-instance**

I am getting error message below:

**ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Your platform does not support OpenSSH.**

Can someone please help me in this regard.

Thanks

Shiv

Comment: Can you add to your post redacted output of [gcloud info] command?

Comment: @shankarsh15 Are you still experiencing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your local Cloud SDK and run ssh command again. To [update the Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update) use the following command:

**gcloud components update**

Comment: I tried running gcloud compoenents update but still getting the same error:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud components update

All components are up to date.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud compute ssh example-instance
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Your platform does not support OpenSSH.

Comment: Actually, I want to create a Kubernetes Cluster on it and expose a Micro service on the cluster through a Docker Image. Trying for sometime now but not able to get through. Your help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @shankarsh15 where are running the 'gcloud compute ssh' command from? what is your OS? Did you try to ssh into the instance from the cloud console?

Comment: I am running 'gcloud compute ssh' command from windows 8.1 (google cloud SDK shell which is installed on a machine when we install google cloud SDK. As you suggested I tried running ssh directly from cloud console after logging into Google Cloud Platform and its working fine. I am just wondering why it is not working directly from cloud SDK shell.

Comment: @shankarsh15 Did you try running the Cloud SDK shell as administrator?

Comment: I tried running as administrator as well but its not  working.

Comment: @shankarsh15 I was able to find this Google Groups thread [1] that might help you resolve the issue. [1]: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gce-discussion/ga63Y_cRiak/Riam3Ng6CgAJ

Answer (score -1):

The error is pretty much self-explanatory. You need to install an OpenSSH to operate. Try installing OpenSSH. The guide for installing on Windows 10 is as follows:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse